# Can't enable rabbitmq-management plugin on Windows 7

Tags: rabbitmq

I had installed Erlang and RabbitMQ. After I started RabbitMQ service. All those step were done without errors. But when I ran:  C:...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
I got following error:

> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@AZE-PC05478... failed.  *
>   Could not contact node rabbit@AZE-PC05478.    Changes will take effect
>   at broker restart.  * Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be
>   contacted.
>               --offline - do not try to contact broker.

I copied .erlang.cookie from /Windows to C:. But I still have the same result. 
Is anything I missed? Thank you for help.

**More infos**: When I added : rabbitmqctl.bat status. I got:

```
Status of node 'rabbit@AZE-PC05478'
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@AZE-PC05478': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@AZE-PC05478']

rabbit@AZE-PC05478:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on AZE-PC05478
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-74@AZE-PC05478'
- home dir: C:\
- cookie hash: 1jjD3t2FUFyx/xXyPe0s4w==
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please add the output of `rabbitmqctl.bat status` to your question?

Comment: Thank you Jean; I added the result on more infos.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, RabbitMQ had issues with hostnames being reported sometimes in lowercase, sometimes in uppercase, and this doesn't play well with Erlang distribution.

It was fixed in RabbitMQ 3.6.0:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/commit/1fb451090a2557f35a2800f9d04c476ff1ad6a22

I suppose you're hitting this problem, because the output of `rabbitmqctl` shows that RabbitMQ is running:

> `epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672`

It's just that `rabbitmqctl` fails to contact it. You can check this by specifying the lowercase version of your node name on `rabbitmqctl` command line:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@aze-pc05478 status
```

Comment: Thank you Jean for your answer. But i have a question: Right now i have RabbitMQ 3.6.10 and you mean that i should take RabbitMQ 3.6.0 instead ?

Comment: No, 3.6.10 has the fix as well. I assumed you were using 3.5.6 from your question: `(...) But when I ran: C:...\rabbitmq-server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins.bat (...)`

Comment: However, you can't use 3.5.6 command line tools with a 3.6.10 server. This is unsupported and `rabbitmqctl` from 3.5.x doesn't have the fix.